# Azure Functions Proxy doubled https in Uri

Tags: api, azure, proxy, azure-functions

Hi When I create proxy in Azure functions it creates address for the proxy like this: https://https://frontendfnc.azurewebsites.net/api/hello with double https and of course this is not valid address. So when I try to call proxy on address with one https I get "Function host is not running" Is there some bug? I am creating proxy thru Azure portal.

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug, and we will investigate. However, it should just be a display issue, and should not affect the runtime. i.e. if you just use one `https://` it should still work.

Comment: I took a look at your app, and the reason it's busted is unrelated to the display issue. You have an `/api/hello` route that points right back to itself, causing an infinite recursion which crashes the host.

Comment: Thanks David. It was indeed the problem together with the fact I forgot to allow anonymous access on backend api.

Comment: Tracked by https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/2369